# jQuery - input autowidth with autocomplete & -internal-input-suggested

Tags: jquery

I want the `input` to `resize` based on the width of the `autocomplete` selection as well as the `-internal-input-suggested`. Currently the input width resizes to the size of the placeholder and value of the input, however autocomplete and -internal-input-suggested currently do not change the width of the input to match the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $inputs = $(".inputs");

  // Resize based on text if text.length > 0
  // Otherwise resize based on the placeholder
  function resizeForText(text) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!text.trim()) {
      text = $this.attr("placeholder").trim();
    }
    var $span = $this.parent().find("span");
    $span.text(text);
    var $inputSize = $span.outerWidth();
    $this.css("width", $inputSize);
  }

  $inputs.find("input").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which && e.charCode) {
      var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode);
      var $this = $(this);
      resizeForText.call($this, $this.val() + c);
    }
  });

  // Backspace event only fires for keyup
  $inputs.find("input").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) {
      resizeForText.call($(this), $(this).val());
    }
  });

  $inputs.find("input").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    resizeForText.call($this, $this.val());
  });
});
```

```css
.inputs input,
.inputs span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 5px;
}
.inputs span  {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  <input autocomplete="email" placeholder="placeholder" />
  <span style="display:none"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Here a nice article on detecting autofill using js
https://medium.com/@brunn/detecting-autofilled-fields-in-javascript-aed598d25da7

Comment: @sagar1025 this looks interesting. Would you be able provide an answer incorporating this method with the auto-width code in the snippet?

Comment: can you make a demo with autocomplete ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `keypress` and `keyup`, why not just use the `input` event?
Also, I don't see the need for the hidden `span` element that's being used just to calculate the width. A neat trick in CSS is to use the `ch` unit rather than `px` if you need to set the width equal to the length of the text.

`1ch` is approximately equal to the width of 1 character.

In `jquery` the `input` event is fired for autofill and every time a value is entered in the input field.

I'm also binding the `blur` event in case autofill fills out other fields.

Initially set the width of the `input` to `11ch` because the length of "placeholder" is 11 characters.

```
.inputs input {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: inherit;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 11ch;
  max-width: 50ch;
}
```

This is what the JS should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $(".inputs");
  
  //this binds all input fields. No need for loop.
  $("input").on('blur input', function() {
    var inputLength = $(this).val().length;
    if (inputLength > 0) {
      $(this).css("width", inputLength + 'ch');
    } else {
      $(this).css("width", '11ch');
    }
  });

});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rk8tzh47/) if you need it

Comment: Thanks for this however I was seeking a solution that auto-expanded the input on hover of the autocomplete suggestions. If you hover a selection it puts a preview into the input - it is this preview I need the auto-width to recognize and expand accordingly

Comment: I don't think this would be possible. I dont think there's a way to detect mouse events on the autocompelete box